# I want to connect mirth with worldVista ehr and want fomat in hl7 or ccd

Tags: windows-vista, hl7, mirth

I want to connect Mirth with WorldVista (Ehr.dat -database)
Now from above database using mirth connect I want data in HL7 format or 
CCD format 
please guide me any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: did you go through other questions like these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057585/get-patient-data-from-vista-ehr-cprs/18097804#18097804 before posting?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a service in Vista to provide an interface that Mirth can read from. Reading or modifying an internal database of a different application is an interoperability anti-pattern.

If there is no possible integration using services, you can always dump text files in a filesystem and grab them from Mirth with a File Reader source in your communication channel.